# Find the probability using the formula for the number of permutations with repetitions

Tags: probability, permutations

A person has forgotten the PIN code for his SIM card, but remembers that it contains three "fives", and one of the numbers is either a "seven" or "eight". What is the probability of successful login on the first try?

So, i think that because there are two case one of the numbers is either a "seven" or "eight", the answer must be a sum of probabilities in cases of seven and eight. The number of permutations with repetitions in case of 7 is $\frac{4!}{3!1!}=4$, so probability is $\frac{1}{4}$. The same in case of eight: $\frac{1}{4}$. So the answer is $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$. However book says that the correct answer is $\frac{1}{8}$. I see, if i write all possible combinations, but why does my formula doesn't work? Isn't it "or" case?

Answer (score 1):

If there are two cases (7 or 8) you need to sum them in the sample space, so you get $\tfrac{1}{4+4}$. You sum probabilities when there are several possibilities to get to the desired outcome, however here the outcome (the correct code) is unique.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 possible combinations for a PIN with 3 fives and 4 possible position with an unknown last digit.
Now, we know that the last digit is 7 or 8. At the end there are only 2*4=8 possible solutions.
Probability of 1 event out of 8 possible is 1/8.